# How is utf-8 coded string printed to screen in C with printf?

Tags: c, bash, encoding, graphics, utf-8

For below code in C:

```
char s[] = "这个问题";
printf("%s", s);
```

Knew that source file is "UTF-8 Unicode C program text" with `file` command.

How the string is coded after compile? Also utf-8 in the .out file?

When the binary file executed in bash, how the string is coded in memory? Is it also utf-8?

Then, how bash knows the coding scheme and show right character?

Last, now the bash know what to show, but how bytes translated to pixels on the screen? Is there some mapping from bytes to pixels?

In all these processes, is there any encoding or decoding of utf-8?

Comment: That's quite the question. Note that bash, the command interpreter shell, and the terminal emulator (the window showing text) are not the same thing. Your program doesn't talk to bash, it just runs in the same terminal as bash (assuming that bash is the shell you use).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming GCC, [this manual page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html) says that the preprocessor will first translate the character set of the incoming files to the so called *source character set*, which for gcc is UTF-8. So for an UTF-8 file, nothing happens. The default *execution character set* is then used for string constants, and that is (again, for GCC) UTF-8 by default.

So your UTF-8 string "survives" and exists in the executable as a bunch of bytes in UTF-8 encoding.

The terminal also has a character set, and that has to match, the C program does nothing to further translate strings when printed, they're just printed as they are, byte for byte. If the terminal isn't set for UTF-8, you will just get garbage.

As I noted in a comment, bash has nothing to do with this.

Comment: So the terminal is mapped to a file, and the executable write the bytes to the file with io interruption. The terminal can be treated as a device, which map byte to pixels. Is it?

Comment: And mapping byte to pixels is done by the graphic driver.